# MutationObserver syntax error on IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, syntax-error, mutation-observers

I'm working with a MutationObserver to change the values of some variables when I switch the content of a panel (I'm useing Bootstrap tabs). Everything is working just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but for some reason, when I test it with IE, it shows a syntax error in the console and the script breaks. This is my MutationObserver code:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (MutationRecords, MutationObserver) {
        dataTable = null;
        tabla = null;
        tabActiva = $('.tab-content').find('.active');
        formFiltro = tabActiva.find('form');
        tabla = tabActiva.find('table');
    });

    observer.observe(target, {
        childList: true,
        attributeFilter: ['class'],
        subtree: true
    });
```

Console points the error is on the observer.observe(). I don't know what's happening. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Just in case, this is my "target":

```
var target = $('.tab-content > .tab-pane').get(0);
```

Comment: What exactly does it say the error is? That doesn't look like a syntax error

Comment: Screenshot of the debugger: http://prntscr.com/jo9uo6

Comment: If i comment the observer.observe() line, it works, but I need that line.

Comment: Can you post the *actual* error (the one that can be seen in the console)? Whatever IDE that is doesn't give any details

Comment: @CertainPerformance That's the actual error. He provided a screenshot of the console for IE11 as a detached window.

Comment: Essentially, because you don't have `attributes` set to `true`, that could be why it's throwing (and even if it's not a polyfill, worth seeing if IE11 has the same issue).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a `MutationObserver`, it's possible to filter attributes, but only if you are observing element attributes to begin with. Therefore the option `attributeFilter` is only applicable if `attributes` is set to `true`.

If you specify an `attributeFilter` without setting `attributes` to `true`, then IE11 will throw a syntax error, while Chrome and Firefox will just silently ignore `attributeFilter`.

To resolve the syntax error, either set `attributes` to `true` or remove the `attributeFilter`.

Answer (score 4):

1. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit/attributeFilter), if `attributeFilter` property is specified,

> **there's no need** to also set `attributes` to `true`, as it's implied.

2. [DOM Living Standard specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-mutationobserverinit-attributefilter) defines `attributeFilter` as

> Set to a list of attribute local names (without namespace) if not all
>   attribute mutations need to be observed and `attributes` is `true` or
>   **omitted**.

---

- Looks like that's not the case for IE11 - it does not comply with the specification.
- **workaround for IE11**: to set `attributeFilter` set also `attributes: true`.